# Problems with additional trailing slash in when using drush rsync

Tags: drush

If I use drush rsync the output is as follows:

```
user@drupal:~/html$ drush rsync @live @local
You will destroy data from var/www/ and replace with data from root@eso-    
meetu.de:/var/www/virtual/eso-meetu.de/htdocs//
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
root@eso-meetu.de's password: 
rsync: mkdir "/var/www/var/www" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(605) [Receiver=3.0.9]
Could not rsync from                                                [error]
root@eso-meetu.de:/var/www/virtual/eso-meetu.de/htdocs// to var/www/
user@drupal:~/html$
```

The alias file I've created contains:

```
<?php

$aliases['live'] = array(
'uri' => 'www.eso-meetu.de',
'root' => "/var/www/virtual/eso-meetu.de/htdocs",
'remote-user' => 'root',
'remote-host' => 'eso-meetu.de',
'ssh-options' => '-o PasswordAuthentication=yes',
'path-aliases' => array(
'%dump-dir' => '/tmp',

),
'command-specific' => array (
'sql-sync' => array (
'no-cache' => TRUE,
),
),
'databases' => array(
'default' => array(
'default' => array(
'driver' => 'mysql',
'database' => 'meetu_original',
'username' => 'removedhere',
'password' => 'removedhere',
'host' => 'localhost',
'prefix' => '',
'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
 ),
 ),
 ),
 );
 $aliases['local'] = array(
 'uri' => 'www.drupal.dev',
 'root' => 'var/www',
 'databases' => array(
 'default' => array(
 'default' => array(
 'driver' => 'mysql',
 'database' => 'drupal',
 'username' => 'drupal',
 'password' => 'drupal',
 'host' => 'localhost',
 'prefix' => '',
 'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci', 
 ),
 ),
 ),
 );'
```

I have no Idea how to get rid of the sceond slash behind htdocs This shalsh causes an rsync error.

Has anybody an idea what I have to do here?

Comment: Your local root needs a leading slash (should be /var/www)

Comment: even if I add this the additional slash harms drush from doing it's work